# Confusion about a boundary condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics, boundary-conditions

In Griffiths' Electrodynamics book, there is an example in Chapter 4 (no. 7 in 4th edition). I am confused about the third boundary condition as shown in the image. How do we get that?

[image]

Comment: You are not asking about a conceptual difficulty. You are asking how to get the answer provided.

Comment: When did I even mention that I was asking a conceptual question? I was just confused about the third boundary condition. That's it.

Comment: Well, $r \cos \theta = x$, so it's just saying $V = - E_0 x$. It basically means "far away from the sphere, the sphere doesn't matter, and the potential is close to what it would have been without the sphere at all."

Comment: @knzhou : This looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Avery : Site policy for such exercises is that you must **show effort to solve the problem** and **ask about a conceptual difficulty**.

Comment: @sammygerbil I do not think I can solve the problem without first understanding what the boundary condition is telling me.

Comment: Deriving the particular boundary conditions for this situation is part of the problem to be solved. They are part of the solution. That is why they are not given in the question.

Comment: I do not see it that way. The Boundary Conditions are not something you always need to derive with huge mathematical effort. It is just about seeing the setup and imposing them on the system. The aforementioned comment by @knzhou did not actually derive anything. He made it obvious in a mathematical way. That was where I was stuck.

Comment: I disagree. The boundary condition has both mathematical and physical content, and it is legitimate to ask questions about that. It can be explained without saying nothing about the rest of the problem. I will proceed to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you understand the first two boundary conditions (continuity of the potential at the boundary and discontinuity of the derivative, the electric field).

The third boundary condition has to do with the fact that, far away from the sphere, you should have the non perturbed external field to determine the potential. Let us assume that the field is oriented along the $z$ direction: then the potential is
$$
V(z)=-E_0 z
$$
far away from the sphere, $|z|>>R$.

Now, you use spherical coordinates to describe the field as you have a spherical dielectric. This is the reason of the awkward form: in spherical coordinates, $z=r\cos\theta$, so we recover the boundary condition. Remember that $\vec{r}$ (position of the particle) and $z\hat z$ (third component of the position in cartesian coordinates) can be joined to form a right triangle of angle $\theta$ adjacent to $z$, hence the result and its interpretation.

So, to summarize, you are just passing to spherical coordinates, where the boundary condition can be expressed as
$$
V(r,\theta,\phi)=-E_0r\cos\theta\quad\quad (r>>R)
$$
Now that you have the boundary conditions, you can solve the differential equation.